# How would I express multiple intervals in this problem?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm told to find which intervals $\left[a,b\right]$ in $\mathbb R$ is the intersection $\left[a,b\right]\cap\mathbb Q$ a clopen subset of the metric space $\mathbb Q$? My first thought was that one could be $\left[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2\right]$, but then I realized that both ends of the interval would be closed. So how would I express multiple intervals if I'm having a hard time trying to express one?

Comment: It seems like you have a good insight.  What exactly do you mean by "both ends of the interval would be closed"?

Comment: I mean that $\pm\sqrt2$ would be like a boundary point, which would indicate that the interval is closed on both sides. Because of course $\pm\sqrt2\not\in \mathbb Q$. So what direction should I go to find a part of the interval that's open?

Comment: While $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$, we can't quite speak of it being an interval of $\mathbb{Q}$ since there the endpoints are "missing".  Concentrate on the question of whether $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is both closed and open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @hardmath So, in $\mathbb Q$ the interval would be open because $-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2$ would be a limit points, but as an interval in $\mathbb R$ it would be closed because they are boundary points. Is that towards the right way?

Comment: In $\mathbb Q, \sqrt 2$ is not a limit point because it is not part of $\mathbb Q$.  So $(-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb Q$. Every number in it is a limit of a sequence within the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The metric topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as its subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$, so a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is both closed and open iff it is both the intersection of a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ and the intersection of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Spoiler:**

> $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}] \cap \mathbb{Q} = (-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: +1 This is the same idea as my comment on the question, expressed in different words.  I hope the two together help Kyle.

Comment: Yes I do understand this now and it makes perfect sense. But now I'm just confused as to how I would show that the metric topology on $\mathbb Q$ is the same as its subspace topology from $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Kyle: The usual metric on $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the one inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you want to find all intervals that satisfy your requests, you could consider density of $Q$ on $R$ to verify that a set such as $[-\sqrt(2),\sqrt(2)]$ is open if you intersect with $Q$. For closure you should consider that the border of you given set is empty.